# Is it possible to access the Mac Address book API from pure Java?

Tags: java, macos, addressbook

Just wondering if it is possible to access the Mac OS X Address Book API's from pure Java 6 code? I want to keep this completely platform independent as my program is built for Windows & Linux also (open source & free: http://jsmsirl.sourceforge.net/).

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way, as far as I know.  Apple has a guide for accessing the address book through JNI though, which is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/java/jniuniversal.html).  The sample code for MyFirstJNIProject is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/MyFirstJNIProject/index.html).

The guide also shows how to check the underlying operating system and only call the JNI code when running on Mac OS X platforms.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 AddressBook-v22.abcddb
and You have access to all data from Address Book, now some SQL statements and You're done:

select * from ZABCDCONTACTINDEX;

for example

HF

Comment: What?? **Mac** Address book is not just an Address Book data application.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way of doing it by using the Rococoa library.

I've described how it's done [here](http://finbarrbrady.com/2010/03/accessing-cocoa-frameworks-from-java/).

Answer (score 1):

I know previous post (the one downvoted to -1 about sqlite3) isn't related to the question beeing asked (and also isn't this one), however it was helpful for me. I'm working in a program where I'm given a .abbu file and I need to import the data to my product AddressBook and that post was my "salvation".